# AngularJS not everything as view?

Tags: angularjs, view, partial-views, partial

I am trying to have a single-page Angular-App which has a view in the middle and tools like sidebar and topbar around that. But when the user is not logged in, the view should show a login partial and the side- and topbar should be hidden. As well as there should be a fullscreen background image. I got a working attempt, but it's rather ugly, so I wonder how I could do better:

```
<body ng-app ="MB">

  <div ng-controller="mbMainCtrl as mainCtrl" class="container-fluid">
    <!--fullscreen background when not logged in-->  
    <div ng-hide="$root.loggedIn" class="landing" ng-cloak>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div ng-show="$root.loggedIn" class="row">

        <mb-topbar></mb-topbar>

      </div>

      <div class="row">

        <div ng-show="$root.loggedIn" class="col-sm-1">
        </div>

        <div  ng-show="$root.loggedIn" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
          <mb-sidebar></mb-sidebar>
        </div>

        <!--view always visible, loads the login page as well-->
        <div class = "col-sm-6">
          <div ng-view></div>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="$root.loggedIn" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div mb-news-feed-dir></div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div mb-quest-feed-dir></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="$root.loggedIn" class="col-sm-1">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use ui-router and have a nested view to accomplish something like this in a more clean way without having to hide and show dom elements.